# Using a custom NUGET package

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have a library class that I've turned into a NUGET package (or created a package from).
I am hosting it on a shared drive and managed to get it to show up in the package manager (and also install it). But after that I can't seem to find a way to actually use it in code.

I thought I could just use the name space that the original code is using like this:

```
using CompanyName.WriteAssistant
```

Or just do `using CompanyName` and then `var test = WriteAssistant.Write(someObject)`, but neither seem to work.

I have also noticed that the contents of the package, after being downloaded to the project where I want to use it, is literally just the entire solution folder of the original project, whereas most packages seem to be much smaller with just a nupckg file.

Here is my nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>WriteAssistant</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>parrotmaster</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <!-- <icon>icon.png</icon> -->
    <description>Allow writing data to file</description>
    <releaseNotes>Inital version.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>writing write file</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.1">
        <dependency id="CompanyWriteAssistant" version="1.0.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: It sounds like the generation of the package is not what you think. You can see the contents of the package using nuget package explorer: https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9WZDNCRDMDM3

Comment: @HenrikGering I was expecting just the dll, and maybe a config or other file to hold the package information like version number etc. I'm guessing I need to put the dll I generate with my project in a seperate solution and then package that?

Comment: It depends on how and where you generate the package. But I think you should loopk into your system for generating the package, as i suspect that is where your error is. The easiest way i know of is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: @HenrikGering Yeah I followed that guide. Sadly that's how I got here.

Comment: I think you should create a new question detailing how you generate your nuget package.

Comment: @HenrikGering That feels like a pointless exercise if following the Microsoft guide got me problems. Isn't there supposed to be anywhere where the person generating the package can specify the name for it to use in code?